# saving actual images on web or the dataURL of it

Tags: django, image, data-url

I am almost finished with creating my webapp. The backend uses Django. This project among aother things lets user upload their own images and make adjustments on them using CamanJS. The images could be of varied size, (5mp or more) and variety of colors. To put it in numbers user might have approx. 60 images for each of his client, and might have to 1000 clients. So if we take on of the worst scenarios and say each image is about 3mb we have

```
3x60 = 180mb for a client
1000x180 = 180.000mb or 180GB for all clients
```

Knowing that my application will be online (probably on a pass) and probably have many users what is the best way to deal with the image size? Is it better if I just saved tha dataURL to the database(base64 format). Will this reduce size of the hd space the project needs? I must say it is important that the images don't loose their initial details. So if a compressions is to be applied it needs not to lessen the image's quality. What do you think would be the best solution?

Comment: Won't compression make quality loss?

Comment: hmmm...So I cannot reduce cost without losing image quality right?Having so much space for a web app is adding a lot to a saas cost?

Comment: I've moved my comments to an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Saving an image Base64-encoded will require about 33% more space — each chunk of 3 orginal bytes is represented as 4 bytes in Base64 encoding. If your images are JPEG, you cannot expect to gain any meaningful additional compression without compromising the image quality.

JPEG images are already compressed. Additional lossless compression (e.g. zip) will likely result in larger files, so your only option is lossy compression at a lower quality. Also note that any modification of a JPEG image requires it to be compressed again, and you lose a bit of quality every time you re-encode a JPEG file. If you want to make repeated adjustments on an image, it would be best to use a lossless compression format (e.g. PNG), but those result in much larger files than JPEG.

If you're going to provide an image service of that scale, the best solution would be to store your images as regular files in your filesystem, and *actually provide* the storage capacity needed for those files. Storing the images in a database is not going to give you a performance benefit, and will most certainly require more space than filesystem storage (though probably not by much). If necessary, performance can be improved by using solid-state storage (flash drives) and/or RAID arrays, if you were using physical infrastructure. With SaaS you don't have much control over your storage, but your service provider is likely already employing such strategies.

I don't see an easy way to reduce the cost for storing 60000 5mpix images per user on a SaaS service. Investing in a dedicated physical infrastructure might lower that cost a bit, but maintaining your own hardware would also have its cost. You will probably need to factor your storage cost into the price of the service you're trying to provide.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution, I think, would be to resize the images smaller before saving them.

An HD photograph can have very large dimensions. Even bigger than the size of monitors. So, if you resize those images smaller before saving, you'd save a significant amount of space.

For instance, I have a photograph on my computer called *forest.jpg* of **size 1.80 MB** and dimensions of 3212x2150 px. The dimensions of my monitor are 1366x768 px. You see, the width of the photograph is more than double the width of my monitor.

And here's what I did:

```
>>> from PIL import Image
>>> photo = "C:/users/weasel/desktop/forest.jpg"
>>> im = Image.open(photo)
>>> size = (1000, 1000)
>>> im.thumbnail(size, Image.ANTIALIAS) # thumbnail will maintain the aspect ratio
>>> out_photo = "C:/users/weasel/desktop/forest_resized.jpg"
>>> im.save(out_photo, 'JPEG', quality=85)
```

The new image that `PIL` thus created had dimensions 1000x669 px and **size 203 KB**. The loss in quality that thus occurred is, I believe, undetectable by human eye.

Comment: I don't think I do have many options here. I also should point that one of the things a user can do with the image is scale it. The image is usualy scaled down when presented to the canvas, but it can scale up to the amount user wants it. E.g the image might be as u say 3212x2150 px but I will present it inside a 800x600 canvas(rataining ratio). Then the user can scale it up 2x or 3x times. Will a resized image have a lot worst quality than the original when scaled up so much times?

Comment: @Apostolos Well, images scaled upto 2x won't look look _so bad_, the pixels will look bigger and shattered. But scaling the image 3x will definitely make it look _bad_.

Comment: How does thumbnail compress images? Because I noticed that when running this code 
img = Image.open(path)
img.thumbnail(img.size)
img.save(new_path, 'JPEG')
it still reduces the size a lot. How is this possible?What does thumbnail do?I used a 3504x2336px image and from 1.7mb it was reduced to 393.6kb. That's a lot, but maintains the original size.

Comment: @Apostolos That happened because when you did `img.save(new_path, 'JPEG')`, the `quality=75` is set by default.

Comment: @Apostolos And as a side note, use `Image.ANTIALIAS` in `img.thumnail` whenever you're resizing the images. It helps maintaining the quality of the image.

Comment: Thank you weasel, I am sticking with quality=90 and the initial size. Because these might be medical content so it needs all of its details

Comment: @Apostolos Be careful when using `quality=90` as in some cases the new generated images might end up having greater memory-size than the original ones.

Comment: How come this is happening?